# Ubuntu installation windows

Tags: system-installation

Can Ubuntu be installed on an old laptop as an operating system?  Is Ubuntu an operating system or does it operate as a browser only?

Comment: ubuntu is indeed an os

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is an OS in the same way OS X, Windows, Solaris, and FreeBSD are OSes. It is the second and third to deepest software configurable, user updatable and changeable, parts of a computer right after the bios. Think of it as what you run all your programs and stuff in, not a program itself but instead a very complex collection of modules that make a computer work as we think they work.

Comment: You may want to expand on or otherwise explain what you mean by "second and third to deepest."